# HTML5 - delay canvas drawing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a simple chunk of code to draw a line in a page. My problem is that I don't know much about HTML5 or JS and I need help to set a delay on the drawing of this line.
I want to be able to choose if I want to see it drawing instantly when opening the page or define it to have 5 seconds delay before being draw.

Here it is:

```
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="1250" height="120"></canvas>

<script>

var canvas = $("#myCanvas")[0];
var c = canvas.getContext("2d");
var amount = 0;
var startX = 164;
var startY = 120;
var endX = 1094;
var endY = 120;

setInterval(function() {
    amount += 0.01; // change to alter duration
    if (amount > 1) amount = 1;
    c.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    c.strokeStyle = "black";
    c.lineWidth=1;
    c.strokeStyle="#707070";
    c.moveTo(startX, startY);
    // lerp : a  + (b - a) * f
    c.lineTo(startX + (endX - startX) * amount, startY + (endY - startY) * amount);
    c.stroke();
}, 0);

</script>
```

Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 7):

Wrap it in a setTimeout:

```
var canvas = $("#myCanvas")[0];
var c = canvas.getContext("2d");
var amount = 0;
var startX = 164;
var startY = 120;
var endX = 1094;
var endY = 120;

setTimeout(function() {
    var interval = setInterval(function() {
        amount += 0.01; // change to alter duration
        if (amount > 1) {
            amount = 1;
            clearInterval(interval);
        }
        c.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        c.strokeStyle = "black";
        c.lineWidth=1;
        c.strokeStyle="#707070";
        c.moveTo(startX, startY);
        // lerp : a  + (b - a) * f
        c.lineTo(startX + (endX - startX) * amount, startY + (endY - startY) * amount);
        c.stroke();
    }, 0);

}, 3000);
```

The above waits 3 seconds (3000 milliseconds) before starting the drawing. Also, whenever you start an interval with setInterval you should store the return value so you can stop the interval later. The code above stops the interval when it's done drawing with clearInterval().

Comment: Is there a way to make this line draw inside a div with fixed position? I'm asking this because the line moves in the <body> when I stretch my browser window.

Comment: BTW, is easing of the movement possible too?

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `setTimeout`:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    setInterval(function() {
        amount += 0.01; // change to alter duration
        if (amount > 1) amount = 1;
        c.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        c.strokeStyle = "black";
        c.lineWidth=1;
        c.strokeStyle="#707070";
        c.moveTo(startX, startY);
        // lerp : a  + (b - a) * f
        c.lineTo(startX + (endX - startX) * amount, startY + (endY - startY) * amount);
        c.stroke();
    }, 0);
}, 5000);
```

Comment: You're adding 5 seconds of delay between frames of an animation.

Comment: he needs setTimeout, not setInterval, you should edit your answer

Comment: @meagar Absolutely right. Just updated the answer, please revise

Answer (score 2):

Wrap your `setInterval` call in a `setTimeout` call. `setInterval` invokes its function argument repeatedly, where the second argument specifies the delay between invocations. `setTimeout` invokes its function argument *once*, after the delay has passed.

```
function redraw() {
  amount += 0.01; // change to alter duration
  if (amount > 1) amount = 1;
  c.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  c.strokeStyle = "black";
  c.lineWidth=1;
  c.strokeStyle="#707070";
  c.moveTo(startX, startY);
  // lerp : a  + (b - a) * f
  c.lineTo(startX + (endX - startX) * amount, startY + (endY - startY) * amount);
  c.stroke();
}


setTimeout(function () { setInterval(redraw, 0) }, 5000);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.setTimeout). setTimeout runs a call after a certain delay.

The function used in your script, [setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.setInterval), runs the same function over and over again at a certain interval. [Strile's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12604979/855738) should help you

Answer (score 0):

**Short answer**

Use [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.setTimeout) function to delay execution. What [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.setTimeout) does is set up a timer which will execute specified function after specified amount of time. E.g.

```
setTimeout(function() {
    alert("Hello!");
}, 5000);
```

will show an alert after 5 seconds (note that time is specified in milliseconds).

---

**Long answer**

There are two functions that allow you to schedule a function execution.

- [setTimeout(func, delay)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.setTimeout) which will execute given function after given delay. This one is used for one-off execution of functions.
- [setInterval(func, delay)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.setInterval) which will execute given function repeatedly after delay passes. After initial delay, specified function will be executed. Timer will then be reset and function will be executed again once delay passes once more, and so on.

Both functions can be canceled using their counterparts ([`clearTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.clearTimeout) and [`clearInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.clearInterval)).